# Dispatch with redux thunk

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm currently learning redux-thunk and met a strange syntax of using the function returning function.

```
const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(anecdoteService.initializeAnecdotes())
  }, [dispatch])
```

which also can be rewritten as

```
const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    anecdoteService.initializeAnecdotes()(dispatch)
  }, [dispatch])
```

initializeAnecdotes definition is

```
const initializeAnecdotes = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const anecdotes = await getAll()
    dispatch({
      type: 'INIT_ANECDOTES',
      data: anecdotes,
    })
  }
}
```

Both of them work (at least for me) and my question is how does the first version works?

Comment: what is the reason of putting `[dispatch]` in the dependency array?

Comment: React hooks lint rules don't allow that and keep warning I should place it in the dependency list. You can read more about it in redux docs

Comment: You can use `useSelector` to load the data. `useEffect` with `store.dispatch` dependency is not right approach. Actually in `useEffect` we should observe component level objects, if you observe outside objects then your component will reload whenever outside object changes.

Comment: *"my question is how does the first version works?"* redux-thunk allows you to dispatch functions which be called: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/290acf90fa5afac5b49f286bb3d8fc51aa864ed3/src/index.js#L3-L5 . If you didn't use redux-thunk you would get an error.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it is new feature, so I was quite confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

redux-thunk allows you to dispatch functions which be called: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js If you didn't use redux-thunk you would get an error.